# Red 'X' image on Network Adapter Icon in Network Connections - Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, ethernet, services, network-adapter, windows-services

Opened **Network Connections** window in **Windows 10 v.1909** (Network and Sharing Center > Change Adapter Settings) only to find that my Primary Ethernet Adapter is displaying a Red 'X' as part of the icon:

[image: Red X on Ethernet Adapter]

I have run 'Diagnose this connection' and found no errors and the Ethernet connection does not seem to have any connectivity issues.

The icon in the system tray displays correctly.

Does anyone know the cause of this error? Are other people experiencing this problem?

**EDIT:** The red 'X' disappears if you disable the **Network List Service** service in Services.msc. So, this resolves the symptom but doesn't fully explain the cause. Is anyone with in-depth knowledge of this service willing to hazard a guess?

**EDIT2:** The above workaround (stopping Network List Service) also breaks the system-tray icon, which starts reporting 'Not Connected - Connections are available'.

**EDIT3:** ReInstalling the **Network Adapter Driver** solved the problem, but it still doesn't explain the *cause*. Would appreciate further information from anyone with leads on what caused this in the first place...

Comment: This could be a simple image caching problem. What happens if you reboot (not to be confused with shutdown, you really need to reboot) the computer?

Comment: The problem persists. Would be curious to see if other people running version 1909 get the same problem. Might just be an OS version bug...

Comment: I run 1909 myself, no issues at all, and I almost all of our customers run 1909 and I see no problems there either. Its on your end.

Comment: Only thing I can think of doing is reinstalling the OS. I'll try conducting research around the icon but am worried these anomalies point to more serious issues so it's a bit out of my depth.

Comment: I got rid of the 'X' by stopping the Network List Service service (services.msc). However, this is more a workaround than a full expalanation of what caused the problem in the first place. Still, it resolved the direct issue itself.